# What if std::vector::insert(pos, value) with an invalid pos?

Tags: c++, exception, vector, standards, c++20

According to [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert):

> `constexpr iterator insert( const_iterator pos, const T& value );`
>
> **Return value**
>
> Iterator pointing to the inserted value.
>
> **Complexity**
>
> Constant plus linear in the distance between pos and end of the container.
>
> **Exceptions**
>
> If an exception is thrown when inserting a single element at the end, and T is CopyInsertable or
> std::is_nothrow_move_constructible::value is true, there are no
> effects (strong exception guarantee).

If `pos` is invalid, the documentation doesn't clearly describe the following issues:

1. What's the return value?
2. Whether an exception will be thrown?

So, my question is:

**What if** `std::vector::insert(pos, value)` **with an invalid** `pos`**?**

Comment: With vector you cannot even check if pos is valid without UB since it is usually a raw pointer and less/greater pointer comparison is UB if the pointers don't belong to the same object or array.

Comment: @dewaffled: That’s undefined behavior in C but nerely an unspecified `bool` in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::vector` is a sequence container. [Table 77: Sequence container requirements](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/sequence.reqmts#tab:container.seq.req) listes the first argument of every `insert` overload as being `p` which is defined [just before the table](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/sequence.reqmts#3.9) as : *"`p` denotes a valid constant iterator to `a`"* where `a` is the vector.

So the position iterator is required to be a valid iterator to `a`. Unless a different consequence is described, failing to respect a requirement of a feature is by default Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 1):

[Iteator requirements, 15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/iterator.requirements#general-15)

> (15) An invalid iterator is an iterator that may be singular (223)
>
> (223) This definition applies to pointers, since pointers are iterators. The
> effect of dereferencing an iterator that has been invalidated is
> undefined.